# Why does QnAMaker Bot does not work in Azure Web Chat channel but works locally

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I was able to convert my EchoBot to interact with QnAMaker as per instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-add-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) on my local development system but when I publish the same using kudu repo (*tried using Azure DevOps service Ci/CD pipeline but it does not work [in preview] because after deployment the bot just hangs on portal and never able to test it on web chat.. so gave up and used recommended kudu repo*), I do not get the correct answer to my response. For every question I send, it is unable to detect the QnAMaker service. And I am returning error message from the code that says no QnaMaker answer was found.

**How do I troubleshoot to identify the cause of this?**
My bot file seems to be working fine locally and I am able to get the answer from QnAMaker locally but not after publishing the code to my  **Web App Bot** in Azure.

I feel like **Botframework V4** (using .net) is not very straight forward and the instruction on the portal (document) is still kind of evolving or sometime incomprehensible.

Here is the snapshot from my emulator while testing the chat locally:

[image]

And here is the snapshot of production endpoint (using the same questions on portal) with my error msg from OnTurnAsync function:
 [image]

My .bot has all the services defined and local bot is working fine.

This is the code in my ChatBot class:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Handle Message activity type, which is the main activity type for shown within a conversational interface
            // Message activities may contain text, speech, interactive cards, and binary or unknown attachments.
            // see https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                // Get the conversation state from the turn context.
                var state = await _accessors.CounterState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CounterState());

                // Bump the turn count for this conversation.
                state.TurnCount++;

                // Set the property using the accessor.
                await _accessors.CounterState.SetAsync(turnContext, state);

                // Save the new turn count into the conversation state.
                await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);

                // Echo back to the user whatever they typed.
                //var responseMessage = $"Turn {state.TurnCount}: You sent '{turnContext.Activity.Text}'\n";
                //await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(responseMessage);

                // QnAService
                foreach(var qnaService in _qnaServices)
                {
                    var response = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
                    if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
                    {
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                            response[0].Answer,
                            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var msg = "No QnA Maker answers were found. Something went wrong...!!";
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(msg, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you manage endpoint configurations for QnA maker? AppSettings? Environment variables? .bot file? Is it possible that you haven't configured everything correctly in the production environment?

Comment: I have local app, then I created another web app bot, download it, copied its bot file to local bot project, updated appsettings.json with correct bot path name and empty fileSecrets,  and then published the local bot project to web app bot (deleted the secret in the portal) and then clicked on Test Web Chat. Now the Web Chat is not giving me correct answer. Everything as per the docs instruction. But still could not get it to work. Are there some instruction that I need to be aware of which is not documented? Followed everything to the letter.

Comment: I am using bot file which I configured for QnaMaker as per instructions documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-add-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: @Andy, a few questions for you. Which SDK are you using? How are you publishing? Is this thru Visual Studio or via a GitHub account or some other?

Comment: @Steven Botframework .net SDK V4. I am publishing via Kudu (local git) on App Service used for bot.

Comment: I got it working after I downloaded the QnAMaker sample and deploying using AZ CLI Publish command. You have to wait for 2 to 3 min after AZ CLI publish command for it work. I created a new Bot (basic bot) and downloaded the code, decrypted the bot file, copied it to my QnAMaker local VS.Net project, changed the appsetting.json to point to the new bot file I copied to my project after decryption, published using az cli publish,  tested on local emulator with development and production endpoint. Short story is if you miss any small minor details then you are doomed and start from the beginning.

Comment: There is some issue with the filesecret setting on the portal which I am not quite sure ...! I noticed that I do not have to delete the filesecret on portal after publishing my bot. But the instruction is saying to delete it (if you follow the doc here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and then the second tutorial to convert the echo bot to qnaMaker based bot does not have any reference to it. So kind of confusing if you do not follow the steps correctly. The whole deployment can be nightmare if u stuck.

Comment: @Andy, glad you were able to get it working. As for the docs, unfortunately, they are imperfect. Best of luck!